# Marquee text from database showing underneath each other rather than inline

Tags: html, marquee

I am pulling text from fields in a database, but the marquee stacks them on top of one another instead of consecutively. How can I rectifiy this? My code it...

```
<div class="messageholder" style="padding-top:8px">
<marquee scrolldelay="190">
<div data-binding-id="repeat1" data-binding-repeat="{{DETAILS.data}}">
*** {{MESSAGE}} ***
</div>
</marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please paste working JSFiddle (or similar), is not clear what you exactly have and what you exactly need.

Comment: Didn't see marquee tag so long (it is obsolete, btw, and you should use something else: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)... Also, it is not really clear what happens -> setup example, if possible.

Comment: And you can also clear your questions, in this case we don't care that you have text from database and also any "helo" and "thanks" statements are not needed - just ask what you need, without any "decorations". See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok will try to set up a jsfiddle, not sure I can recreate it without the database element, because I think it is the repeating element that makes it function improperly. As to deprecating marquee, I thought it was coming back into favor slightly?

Comment: [This feature (`<marquee>`) is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: maybe I should change the question to "does anybody have an alternative to marquee that will scroll text across the screen when required"?